# Who/what is Killy?

Tags: noise, blame

In [*NOiSE!*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NOiSE) there is a police officer named Killy who is tasked to find a culprit. Later, in *[Blame!](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Blame!)*, there's another character named Killy. I'm not sure if is the same person.

- There are thousands of years between the two works.
- Sanakan says he is a former Safeguard from the city.
- The later Killy seems to be something amid a cyborg and a machine.

If they're the same Killy, what happened to him?  I am wondering if he is a transhuman/cyborg/robot, since Cibo says that Killy does not need to eat often.

Comment: I've edited to clean up the language used. Also there was a sub-question that didn't seem to relate (that you might want to ask as a different question, depending on whether this question answers your sub-question or not).

Comment: Thanks, indeed its better formatted this way. and You are right, I was asking two things.

Comment: As it is, there's still more than one question here...

Comment: @riccs_0x: What can I do to improve my answer?

Comment: @FuzzyBoots, don't worry, your answer is excellent, Its just I'm not sure at all, it isn't your answer, your answer looks pretty solid for me, but this thing does not make sense. I was thinking about several times, but even so I cant say why does not work for me, sorry for the delay. Your answer is right, but I'm sure its not that way.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

### They are not the same character

This note was included in the English translation of *Blame*, which was introduced at the end of *NOiSE!*:

[image: Opening page of *Blame*]

> This is Tsutomy Nihei's award winning debut work in 1995. It's called Blame and the main character is Killy, but the story isn't related to Nihei's later work Blame!, which started to be released in the monthly anthology "Afternoon" at the end of 1997. Though it is quite interesting, how much Nihei developed his skills between the creation of these two mangas.

So no, they are not the same character.